# Is there a concept of routing by id in Spring like there is in rails

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

If I want to get an `Office's` show page in rails, I simply use the url `.../offices/:id`

I have a Spring app and I'm trying to get the same thing happening.  I'm not sure how I can write a href to go to an `office's` `showOffice` page.  I have a controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showOffice", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
    public ModelAndView showOfficePage(Long officeId) {
        Office office = officeServiceImpl.find(officeId);
        ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView("showOffice", "command", office);
        return result;
    }
```

The only thing I could think of was `<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/showOffice(${10})" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">`

Can anybody point me in the right direction?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Spring 3.0 and later supports the @PathVariable annotation for just this case. See the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) for further information.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/offices/{officeId}", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
public ModelAndView showOfficePage(@PathVariable("officeId") Long officeId) {
    Office office = officeServiceImpl.find(officeId);
    ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView("showOffice", "command", office);
    return result;
}
```

Plain-old concatenation will work to construct these URLs in your views:

```
<a href="/offices/<%= offices.id %>" >Link</a>
```